# Change Dock Icons only?

Tags: macos, dock

I just want to change the dock icons instead of system wide.

It it possible to only change the icons in the dock, and not elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Candybar](http://www.panic.com/blog/2012/08/candybar-mountain-lion-and-beyond/). It's free now as it's not as effective in Mountain Lion as it used to be.

Answer (score -1):

Can you be more specific? If you mean add or remove new dock icons on Mac OS, this should work.

*To Add icons:* simply drag any icon from system onto the dock. This should add it automatically.

*To Remove icons:* just hold any icon which you want to remove and drag it onto the desktop and leave, this should remove them.

Comment: Not the app, but the icon of the app (.icns file). I want my Finder icon in my dock to by different from the Finder icon in the Applications folder etc.

Comment: Oh , Download what influenceJamie suggested, Make alias of the applications folder and then change the icns for only alias this will not effect the main application folder icon.

Comment: what do you mean